# Grover's algorithm for game tree

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Scott Aaronson gives the [outline](https://www.scottaaronson.com/qclec/23.pdf) of an algorithm to evaluate whether there exists a satisfying assignment for a given game tree. The idea is to use Grover's search recursively, for each level of the tree. He notes the following problem with this approach.

> The problem is that, as the game tree gets deeper and deeper, the
>   advantage of Grover’s algorithm over classical search ​seems​ to get
>   weaker and weaker, for two reasons: first, the amplification that’s
>   needed at each layer to prevent error buildup, and second, the
>   constant factors, which multiply across the layers. Note that each
>   layer actually needs to run Grover’s algorithm on the layer below it
>   ​twice:​
>
> - Once to do $ |​x\rangle​ \rightarrow |​x\rangle​ |​f(​x​​)\rangle  $
> - And once to  uncompute    garbage.
>
> For this reason, the constant factor $\frac{\pi}{4}$, in the
>   running time of Grover’s algorithm, actually becomes $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and  $\frac{\pi}{2} > 1$.

I don't understand what garbage we are trying to uncompute here. Don't we need to perform some kind of a measurement after the first step which obviates the need to uncompute anything? Can someone explain this approach with a short example (perhaps a depth-2 or a depth-3 game tree)?